# How to declare a const String in stable Rust?

Tags: string, rust, constants, literals

I am trying to declare a `const String` in stable Rust but it does not let me declare it:

```
const CONSTANT_VALUE: String = String::from("constant value");

fn main() {
    println!("{}", TARGET_PORT_KEY);     
}
```

It is saying that:

> Calls in constants are limited to tuple structs and tuple variants

I do not want to declare my `string` as literal and call `to_string()` on literal all the time.

What is the correct way to declare a constant `String` value?

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a5d41c2cac4b5a2ebdf4ef74617baefa)

Comment: A `String` is a growable buffer. Its purpose is to be modifiable. Why would you pass around a `String` if it's meant to be constant? Remember that API should usually take a `&str` as argument, not a `String`. The right constant type **is** `&str`.

Comment: Oh, I see the point. The main reason why I was asking that the API was taking `String` parameters but it seems these parameters are immutable and constant as well so yes I can change them to `&str` as well. Thanks for clearing that out.

Comment: Even if you want an owned string (`String` type), it is better to take an `Into<String>` so that your API is more flexible.